# VBA Outlook 2016 Crear carpetas en subcarpetas de forma automática

Tags: vba, outlook

Estoy organizando e-mail en Outlook 2016 y necesito crear 3 subcarpetas específicas en cada carpeta (tengo que hacer esto en más de 3000 carpetas). Tengo el código que me crea automáticamente estas 3 carpetas en cada carpeta de forma individual:

```
Public Sub CreateFolders()
Dim CurrentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Subfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim List As New VBA.Collection
Dim Folders As Outlook.Folders
Dim Item As Variant

List.Add Array("1", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("2", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("3", olFolderInbox)

Set CurrentFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
Set Folders = CurrentFolder.Folders
For Each Item In List
    Folders.Add Item(0), Item(1)
Next
End Sub
```

(Lo conseguí en https://www.computergaga.com/blog/loop-through-subfolders-using-filesystemobject/)

Lo que no soy capaz de hacer es conseguir que se creen estas tres carpetas de forma automática en todas las subcarpetas de un directorio. He intentado integrar un loop, pero no consigo que funcione. Acabo de empezar a programar y he estado buscando una solución, pero no encuentro nada específico para este problema.

Aprecio cualquier ayuda que podáis proporcionarme.

Answer (score 0):

Si las carpetas a las cuales deseas agregarles las 3 subcarpetas se encuentran en la Bandeja de entrada, puedes utilizar esto.

```
'Cambié la variable CurrentFolder por BandejaDeEntrada para que fuera más descriptiva
Dim BandejaDeEntrada As Outlook.MAPIFolder

'Obtén la carpeta de la Bandeja de entrada
Set BandejaDeEntrada = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
'Por cada carpeta en la Bandeja de entrada
For Each Carpeta In BandejaDeEntrada.Folders
    'Agrega las tres subcarpetas
    For Each Item In List
        Carpeta.Add Item(0), Item(1)
    Next
Next
```

Ahora, en caso de que no sea la Bandeja de entrada donde se encuentran tus carpetas, tienes varios archivos de datos o simplemente desees mantener tu estilo, solo agrega el ciclo For Each.

OJO: Con esta segunda opción también debes tener cuidado de posicionarte en la carpeta en la cual deseas que trabaje tu función ya que estás utilizando ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder para obtener la carpeta actual de la ventana que está abierta y activa.

```
Public Sub CreateFolders()
Dim CurrentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Subfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim List As New VBA.Collection
Dim Folders As Outlook.Folders
Dim Item As Variant

List.Add Array("1", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("2", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("3", olFolderInbox)

Set CurrentFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
For Each Folder In CurrentFolder.Folders 'Agregas este For Each
    For Each Item In List
        Folder.Add Item(0), Item(1)
    Next
End Sub
```